# How to compare a list of datetime.date with a range of date time.date in an IF-conditional?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I've created a range of dates where it I made a variable that will be compared to the dates that are listed in my original file. I am trying to find the occurrence of certain types where the dates in the csv matches the range of dates such as `new_file[15] == ranges` where `new_file[15]` is the row with the dates

```
    def perdelta(start, end, delta):
        """Get a range of dates"""
        curr = start
        while curr < end:
            yield curr
            curr += delta


    Year2014 = perdelta(date(2013, 04, 1), date(2014, 03, 31), timedelta(days=1))
    file = open("pastRMs.csv", "r")
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader,None)
    for ranges in Year2014:
        for another_line in reader:
            objectify_date_list = []
            new = another_line[15]
            objectify_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(new, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
            objectify_date_list.append(objectify_date)
            new_file = another_line[0:15] + objectify_date_list + another_line[16:]
            for data in new_file:
            if data[15] == ranges:
                 print data[17]
```

This code prints the range of dates and the dates in the csv such as: `new_file[15] = 2013-09-14` and `ranges = 2013-04-01` which is within the date range but `new_file[15] == ranges`processes but does not match the date to give me the column I wanted which is `new_file[17]`

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but it seems that  all you are doing is seeing if the dates of the field in the csv are in the range 4/1/2013 - 3/31/2014? If that's the case why can't you do if date1 <=  objectify_date and date2 > objectify_date:

Comment: Oh, what I'm trying to do is to isolate the rows in the csv that are within the range of 4/1/2013 - 3/31/2014. I want to get these rows so I can find another piece of information which is data[17]. I'm going to this over and over again for different range of dates stored in other variables so I don't know if I could have done that.

Comment: If you just want the date in a date range, what I mentioned above will work. If you have a lot of date ranges and a lot of data, then you will want something more advanced because when you have an outer and inner loop like you have above it will slow down rapidly with more data. it's what we call O(n)^2 algorithm. You can easily get this down to an n time algorithm where you go through the list once. The trick is to sort both sets of ranges.